# Pseudo-R^2 Measures from QAP Logistic Regression in R (netlogit in sna package)

Tags: r, logistic-regression, sna

I need to better understand the output from netlogit in the sna package in R. Below you find an example posted online (https://rpubs.com/pjmurphy/338798), which provide a basis for my questions:

1. The results provide two Pseudo-R^2 Measures, (Dn-Dr)/(Dn-Dr+dfn): 0.4250345 and (Dn-Dr)/Dn: 0.5332452. Which are these? What's the difference? How do I interpret them? Is one better to use than the other?
2. What is Total Fraction Correct: 0.875? How do I interpret it?

---

```
nlog<-netlogit(Padgett_Business, list(Padgett_Marriage, Padgett_Party),reps=1000)
summary(nlog)

## Network Logit Model
## 
## Coefficients:
##             Estimate    Exp(b)    Pr(<=b) Pr(>=b) Pr(>=|b|)
## (intercept) -2.57893819 0.0758545 0.000   1.000   0.000    
## x1           2.17792200 8.8279428 0.999   0.001   0.001    
## x2          -0.02228475 0.9779617 0.517   0.483   0.972    
## 
## Goodness of Fit Statistics:
## 
## Null deviance: 332.7106 on 240 degrees of freedom
## Residual deviance: 155.2943 on 237 degrees of freedom
## Chi-Squared test of fit improvement:
##   177.4164 on 3 degrees of freedom, p-value 0 
## AIC: 161.2943    BIC: 171.7362 
## Pseudo-R^2 Measures:
##  (Dn-Dr)/(Dn-Dr+dfn): 0.4250345 
##  (Dn-Dr)/Dn: 0.5332452 
## Contingency Table (predicted (rows) x actual (cols)):
## 
##       0     1
## 0   210    30
## 1     0     0
## 
##  Total Fraction Correct: 0.875 
##  Fraction Predicted 1s Correct: NaN 
##  Fraction Predicted 0s Correct: 0.875 
##  False Negative Rate: 1 
##  False Positive Rate: 0 
## 
## Test Diagnostics:
## 
##  Null Hypothesis: qap 
##  Replications: 1000 
##  Distribution Summary:
## 
##        (intercept)        x1        x2
## Min      -7.240807 -2.540211 -2.995598
## 1stQ     -6.537942 -0.820302 -1.010798
## Median   -6.266030 -0.328922 -0.103392
## Mean     -6.230127  0.049667 -0.006711
## 3rdQ     -5.947601  0.813030  0.899497
## Max      -4.705737  5.194956  4.716553
```

Comment: I talked to a colleague with strong statistical expertise, but without knowledge in R, and he suggested:
1) that it appears like the first Pseudo-R^2 Measure (Dn-Dr)/(Dn-Dr+dfn) corresponds to an adjusted R-square, while the second (Dn-Dr)/Dn) corresponds to a regular R-square. Is that correct? If so, I have an answer to the first questions. 
2) He also suggested that the Total Fraction Correct is a goodness-of-fit measure that state the fraction of modelled values that fall into the same category as the observed value. Is that correct?